Which statistical test to use?
I am trying to understand the relationship between mental health and quality of life with social media addiction and fear of missing out. For mental health and quality of life, I am using quality of life questionnaire by WHO which has four dimensions - physical, psychological, social and environment; and DASS-21 which gives depression, anxiety and stress scores. I want to see if how social media addiction and fear of missing out are connected to the above variables and if time spent on social media and gender play a role in this.
Which statistical test is most suitable to analyse this data?
Thank you

You should consult with a statistician on your project: you'll need more than just the name of a test to run.

I was hoping to learn more about the test if I know how to approach the data.

What is the outcome measure? Scores on a Likert scale?

@AliceD The items are measured on a Likert scale. However, there will be an overall score. For example, DASS scale gives scores for Depression, Anxiety and Stress; social media addiction and fear of missing out will also give a single score

And its's those 'overall scores' you are after? Can these 'overalls' be considered to exist on a continuous scale or are they still represented as integers?

over scores (continuous) for fomo and social media addiction. domain specific scores for quality of life and DASS
